# Classic storage "The selected pricing tier is not supported in this location" Europe West

Tags: azure, storage

I have azure account and some services created on it(web app, database and server, web service and storage account), and noticed that some accounts are created on Europe North and others on Europe West farms. I wanted to move everything, or recreate on Europe West, but run into a problem when creating classic storage account. When I want to create classic storage account in Europe West location, I get the message "The selected pricing tier is not supported in this location". I have a B1 Basic service plan(tried to switch it to S1 but it didn't help). The thing that is bothering me is that my colleague tried to create the same thing from his azure account and he was able to do it. Also, I tried doing the same from my private account(account that it's not working for is company's account), and was also able to do it. I have Pay-as-you-go pricing plan on company's account. I seem to be missing something here and I'm simply not experienced enough in configuring azure, and couldn't find the solution by googling. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure this is a storage question? Saying B1 and S1 make it sound more like you are attempting to create a VM, which may have a related storage account. Also, how are you attempting to create the storage account? Via PowerShell, portal or something else?

Comment: Please confirm if you're dealing with actual storage, as B1 Basic and S1 are usually refererring to performance tiers of Azure SQL Database. Also can you please confirm the status of account, as there are some limitations on a Trial Accounts with Spending Limit being on.

Comment: Yes, I am dealing with the storage. I put the info about Default service plan as I thought it might be relevant. I tried creating it both through portal and old interface. Old interface doesn't even offer Europe West as an option, and in the portal interface, the option is grayed out. Account is active and in Pay-as-you-go subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got the solution. **b0rg** was on a right track. So when I posted the problem here, I was in contact with MS partner company, and they told me that for some reason, when my account was created, options for some locations weren't enabled by default, and I should create a **free billing support ticket through azure portal**. So I did that. Told them what MS partner told me, and within 2 working days they just enabled the options and now I can create the storage in Europe West location. Microsoft.... :/

Answer (score 0):

Please create a ticket with Billing Support via Azure Portal. They should be able to help you with this.